# Python Django request.POST returns no data

Tags: django-views

I don't understand why my request.POST returns empty data. Here is the string I get from the console:

```
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'qPBJWRB3zUubmGYQ4U414asnnNYb22C3'], u'taxiList': [u''], u'deleteTaxi': [u'']}>
```

taxiList is dropdown that contains a few entries.

**views**

```
def admindashboard(request):

    jobsNow = Job.objects.filter(jobstatus = 'd')
    jobsAvailable = Job.objects.filter(jobstatus='p')
    taxis=Taxi.objects.all()
    template = "admindashboard.html"
    form = AdminDashboardForm()


    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = AdminDashboardForm()
    else:

        if request.POST.get("cancelJob"):
            selectedJob = request.POST.get("liveJobs")
            selectedJobObj = Job.objects.get(pk = selectedJob)
            selectedJobObj.jobstatus = 'p'
            selectedJobObj.taxi = None
            selectedJobObj.save()

        elif "deleteTaxi" in request.POST.get():
            test1 = request.POST
            print(test1)
            selectedTaxi = request.POST.get("taxiList")
            selectedTaxiObj = Taxi.objects.get(LicensePlate='MFR011')
            selectedTaxiObj.delete()

        elif request.POST.get("deleteJob"):
            selectedAvailableJob = request.POST.get("availableJobs")
            selectedAvailableJobObj = Job.objects.get(pk= selectedAvailableJob)


        elif request.POST.get("assignJob"):
            selectedAvailableJob = request.POST.get("")

        else:
            test1 = request.POST
            print(test1)

            print("no action was provided")

    return render(request, template, {'jobsNow':jobsNow, 'form':form, 'taxis':taxis, 'jobsAvailable':jobsAvailable })
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h3 class="panel-title">Taxis</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<p>
<select name="taxiList"  class="form-control">
{% for taxis in taxis %}
<option value="{{taxis.LicensePLate}}">{{taxis.LicensePlate}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select></p>
<button name ="addTaxi" onclick="addTaxiFct()" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Ajouter Taxi</button>
<button name="deleteTaxi" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Éffacer Taxi</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Modifier</button> </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My understanding is that `request.POST` should send back a string containing the selected element in the `dropdown`. I'm currently debugging so that is why my model has a different condition for the `deleteTaxi` element.

Comment: Sorry this is what I get in the console: <QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'qPBJWRB3zUubmGYQ4U414asnnNYb22C3'], u'taxiList': [u''], u'deleteTaxi': [u'']}>
I would be expecting taxiList with the selected element,

Comment: also elif "deleteTaxi" in request.POST.get(): is actually elif "deleteTaxi" in request.POST: